# Unity Static member `UpgradeManager.tickValue' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, structure

How can i keep the structure like this, if the tickValue is static?

```
public float GetMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = 0;
    foreach (UpgradeManager item in items)
    {
        tick += item.tickValue;
    }
    return tick;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means your `UpgradeManager` looks as follows

```
public class UpgradeManager 
{
    public static float tickValue;
}
```

remove the `static` keyword and it will work in the context you have in your question.

If you want to use it in a static context you need to access it as follows, but then you can not use it in an instanced object (new UpgradeManager() creates an instance)

```
UpgradeManager.tickValue
```

so using it in your example.

```
public float GetMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = UpgradeManager.tickValue;
    // it cannot be used in a for-loop with each instance referencing it, static is a global, single value.
    return tick;
}
```

but what you may have wanted to do is this

```
public float GetMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = UpgradeManager.tickValue / items.length;
    // it cannot be used in a for-loop with each instance referencing it, static is a global, single value.
    return tick;
}
```

Comment: I know it looks like that, but how could i change that to work? / I dont want to change it from static.

Comment: The problem is that, that i want it to be static to save it.. but if its not static then i cant refer to that in my Save script.

Comment: why on earth do you need it to be static to save it? It is not possible to have instance based static variables. if you need to do this then you may have strange save logic, and should post a new question for help on that

Comment: Type `UpgradeManager[]' does not contain a definition for `length' and no extension method `length' of type `UpgradeManager[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)