# Unity saving foreach?

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, save, load

I'm a bit new to unity please help me.

How can i save something like this?

```
public float GetMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = 0;
    foreach (UpgradeManager item in items)
    {
        tick += item.tickValue;
    }
    return tick;
}
```

Comment: Follow up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999971/unity-static-member-upgrademanager-tickvalue-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instan

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? You could store the result in a variable, I guess?

Comment: I can, but then i cant load it back.

Comment: How long do you need to save it for? The current scene? Game session? Between multiple game sessions?

Comment: I have to save it to a file, so when the player comes back it loads it if you click on the load button, i already have those setup but i only cant save/load this one..

Comment: If you have that set up, please show your current (unsuccessful) attempt to save the value, and we can work from there to see what went wrong.

Comment: I have a static variable called moneypersecond which is equals to tickValue which is in the void Update() and my save looks like this: data.moneypersecond = Upgrademanager.moneypersecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'save' the data in a file you can serialize to a text document using either xml or JSON and deserialize it when the game runs. This is more convenient than player prefs as you can duplicate or edit the values in any text editor with ease.

To persist data between scenes just ensure the class that holds the data is a static class(use the singleton method) or on a class which is set to 'don't destroy on load'.

Comment: I'm currently persisting data between scenes, but i have that code, that i cant make static, so i cant save it. :/ I need a way to make it static, or assign it to a static variable or something, so i can save it, and load it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the variable itself to be static. Any variable on a class that is static will persist during runtime. The method you have returns a value so if you had a class called SaveData with a float property called Tick, then you can say SaveData.Tick = GetMoneyPerSec();  The result goes into the property and you can use it where you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PlayerPrefs`. Let's say you have something like `float tick = GetMoneyPerSec()`, then you store it:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MoneyPerSec", tick);
```

and retrieve it with:

```
float f = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MoneyPerSec");
```

Comment: I'm using Persistence Saving, isn't there a method to save it to there?

Comment: Check out the tutorial on data persistence from unity [persistence](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data)

Comment: I did, thats how i made mine. :/

Comment: Can it be rebuilded to work with the data persistence, and not PlayerPrefs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Gerard Roche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934739/gerard-roche) and [Sakkas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7009147/sakkas) is correct.
To pass data between scenes, all you need is `PlayerPrefs`.
Based on your code, the way to save the `ticks` is:

```
public float CalculateMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = 0;
    foreach (UpgradeManager item in items)
    {
        tick += item.tickValue;
    }
    // save the value after calculation
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MoneyPerSecond", tick);
    return tick;
}
```

And get it from another scene:

```
// Another Scene
public float GetMoneyPerSec()
{
    float tick = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MoneyPerSecond");
}
```

Saving data in `PlayerPrefs` is considered safe since `PlayerPrefs` calls `PlayerPref.Save()` when `OnApplicationQuit()` to write data to the hard disk, and it is the most efficient way for transferring data.